# discord.js prefix throwing error without command

Tags: discord.js

So my bots prefix is `.`, whenever a user just sends `.` the bot responds with `there was an error trying to execute that command!` Which is very annoying. I can not figure out how to get it to not respond to the `.` with the error

This line should be preventing that, but it is not  `const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName)); if (!command) return;`

````
client.on("message", message => {
    const prefixes = ['.'];
    const prefix = prefixes.find(p => message.content.startsWith(p));
    if (!prefix) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));
    
    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.permissions) {
        const authorPerms = message.channel.permissionsFor(message.author);
        if (!authorPerms || !authorPerms.has(command.permissions)) {
            return message.reply('You can not do this!');
        }
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    const { cooldowns } = client;

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }
    
    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 0) * 1000;
    
    if (timestamps.has(message.guild.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.guild.id) + cooldownAmount;
    
        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.guild.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.guild.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(client, message, args, Discord);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});```
````

Comment: What does it console log? Your code shows that you console log the error

Comment: Also that doesn’t prevent it since "." Is considered a string starting with "." (even if the entire string is that)

Answer (score 0):

You should try checking, if the message is longer than the prefix itself, try changing `const prefix` to this:

```js
const prefix = prefixes.find(p => message.content.startsWith(p) && message.content.length>p.length);
```